# Looking for some generic way of tracing path of code in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web app in ASP.NET MVC and C#.
I need to know if there is any way we can have where we can know what db call was made on any given action method. It's MVC architecture and the action methods calls a service layer and that in turn calls data layer where we are using entity framework.
So I am looking for something that can provide what db method call was made for any action and provide that name of the method.
I was trying if we can use reflection, but not very sure if it's possible even. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Unless you mean to find a programmatic way: Are you in a position to locally debug it?  You could put a breakpoint right on the action of the controller you are interested in and start debugging. Keep hitting F11 to step through the code.  You should be able to find the call in the data layer.  Actions can have a none-to-many relationship to any db calls and are so flexible like this I don't see a way to programatically do this.

Comment: No, no. I am not asking that.

Comment: What I am asking is - I want to know what method from the db layer is called from the action and that should be returned in the action method. So whenever a user clicks on any button, some action is called and then it calls the the other underlying classes and methods and then do a db call in entity (db layer) layer. I want to know that db method name and need to display on the UI. So that db method name should be returned / known at action level. And this should be done in a generic way (via some event or some common way). So that is done for any action and any action's db method name is sent

Comment: The code should not be cppy/pasted or repeated for every action.